# Plot.ly: Different height for subplots with shared X-Axes

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

**Background**

- *Distinct subplots (✔) with same height (✘)*

I can create a graph with *Subplots with Shared X-Axes* (example adapted from [Plot.ly doc](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/#subplots-with-shared-xaxes)), with proper separation between subplots and where you can insert a specific title for each subplot via `subplot_titles`:

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[10, 11, 12]
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=[2, 3, 4],
    y=[100, 110, 120],
)
trace3 = go.Scatter(
    x=[3, 4, 5],
    y=[1000, 1100, 1200],
)
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, specs=[[{}], [{}], [{}]],
                          shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=True,
                          vertical_spacing=0.1, subplot_titles=('subtitle 1', 
                          'subtitle 2', 'subtitle 3'))
fig.append_trace(trace1, 3, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace3, 1, 1)

fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=600, title='Subplots with Shared X-Axes')
py.plot(fig, filename='subplots-shared-xaxes')
```

[image]

- *Merged subplots (✘) with distinct height (✔)*

I can also create a graph with *Stacked Subplots with a Shared X-Axis* (example adapted from [Plot.ly doc](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/#stacked-subplots-with-a-shared-xaxis)), where you can define the relative height of each subplot via `domain`:

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[10, 11, 12]
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=[2, 3, 4],
    y=[100, 110, 120],
    yaxis='y2'
)
trace3 = go.Scatter(
    x=[3, 4, 5],
    y=[1000, 1100, 1200],
    yaxis='y3'
)
data = [trace1, trace2, trace3]
layout = go.Layout(
    yaxis=dict(
        domain=[0, 0.25]
    ),
    legend=dict(
        traceorder='reversed'
    ),
    yaxis2=dict(
        domain=[0.25, 0.75]
    ),
    yaxis3=dict(
        domain=[0.75, 1]
    )
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=600, title='Stacked Subplots with Shared X-Axes')
py.plot(fig, filename='stacked-subplots-shared-x-axis')
```

[image]

**Question**

> How to to create *subplots with shared x-axes* where you have **both a title** (fig 1) **and different relative height** (fig 2) **for each subplot**?

---

**What I have tried**

- *Using `subplots` and `rowspan`*

A first hack is to create an additional row make a plot span over two of them:

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[10, 11, 12]
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=[2, 3, 4],
    y=[100, 110, 120],
)
trace3 = go.Scatter(
    x=[3, 4, 5],
    y=[1000, 1100, 1200],
)
fig = tools.make_subplots(
    rows=4,
    cols=1,
    specs=[
        [{}],
        [{'rowspan':2}],
        [None],
        [{}],
    ],
    shared_xaxes=True,
    shared_yaxes=True,
    vertical_spacing=0.1,
    subplot_titles=(
        'subtitle 1',
        'subtitle 2',
        None,
        'subtitle 3',
    )
)
fig.append_trace(trace3, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace1, 4, 1)

fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=600, title='Subplots with Shared X-Axes, span rows')
py.plot(fig, filename='subplots-shared-x-axis-span-rows', auto_open=True)
```

[image]

**The result is exactly what I want to achieve.** However, this hack seems *wrong* to me: syntactically speaking, I don't want a graph that spans over two rows. Moreover, having to add `[None]` to `specs` and `None` to `subplot_titles` is ugly and error-prone if you want to modify anything.

Consider also the case where you want a `13% | 70% | 17%` height distribution of subplots!

- *using `domain`*

A slightly better option is to use update axes with `domain`, yet subplot titles get messed up (they are still evenly vertically distributed):

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[10, 11, 12]
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=[2, 3, 4],
    y=[100, 110, 120],
)
trace3 = go.Scatter(
    x=[3, 4, 5],
    y=[1000, 1100, 1200],
)
fig = tools.make_subplots(
    rows=3,
    cols=1,
    specs=[[{}], [{}], [{}]],
    shared_xaxes=True,
    shared_yaxes=True,
    vertical_spacing=0.1,
    subplot_titles=(
        'subtitle 1',
        'subtitle 2',
        'subtitle 3'
    )
)
fig.append_trace(trace1, 3, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace3, 1, 1)

fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=600, title='Subplots with Shared X-Axes and `domain` hack')
fig['layout']['yaxis1'].update(domain=[0, 0.2])
fig['layout']['yaxis2'].update(domain=[0.3, 0.7])
fig['layout']['yaxis3'].update(domain=[0.8, 1])
py.plot(fig, filename='subplots-shared-x-axis-domain-hack', auto_open=True)
```

[image]

Comment: See an update by plotly devs on [the dedicated thread on Plot.ly community forum](https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-set-different-height-to-subplots-sharing-x-axes/14677).

Comment: See related [bug report on Github](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1229).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bug has been solved by Kully in [PR #1245](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/pull/1245) and **fixed in `dash v3.4.0`**.

[image]

Following code — using only 3 subplots and `row_width=[0.2, 0.4, 0.2]` — should thus work flawlessly:

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[10, 11, 12]
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=[2, 3, 4],
    y=[100, 110, 120],
)
trace3 = go.Scatter(
    x=[3, 4, 5],
    y=[1000, 1100, 1200],
)
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1,
                          shared_xaxes=True,
                          vertical_spacing=0.1,
                          subplot_titles=('subtitle 1', 'subtitle 2', 'subtitle 3'),
                          row_width=[0.2, 0.4, 0.2]
                         )

fig.append_trace(trace1, 3, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace3, 1, 1)

fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=600, title='Subplots with Shared X-Axes')
go.FigureWidget(fig)
```

Comment: can you update the row heights after making the plots? in my case, iterate over a list, create the traces..when i add the traces to a row, i want to set the row height at that time

Comment: Would like to update that 'row_width' has been replaced by the 'row_heights' field, although backward compatibility still exists (https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.subplots.make_subplots.html)